# Is there a .NET library that does what ADOX did, i.e. a cross-db DDL library?

Tags: .net, ado.net, adox

I'm writing a cross database application. When it comes to commands and connections, it works beautifully with ADO.NETs base classes and oledb providers.

Now I need to write some code to make tables, indexes, drop them, query the list of tables, etc and I'm not looking forward to having a dozen versions of that code for MySql, MsSql, MsAccess, SQLite, etc.

How can I achieve this? Is there a library that helps with this, as ADOX did?

Answer (score 1):

ADOX still works with .Net.

Normally DDL manipulation of the database is not that performance intensive, so the extra marshalling to COM does not matter.